# Nested array sorting for bulk data

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, nested

I have the following data as a nested array  please see the below fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/athulmathew/z3s1w0mu/
I want to get the output from the array-like below

```
var item {caller_number_raw : data from the array,company_id:data from the array}
```

I tried to sort it like this

```js
for (i in data.data.hits) {
  for (j in data.data.hits[i]._source) {   
    //str += data.data.hits[i]._source[j] + "<br/>";
    var Item ={CallerID:data.data.hits[i]._source[j].caller_number}       
    console.log(Item) 
  }
}
```

but returns an empty object "{}" I am not that familiar with nested arrays can anybody help me what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_source` is just an `Object`, you don't have to iterate over its property in order to get a specific property, you can replace the second loop with just `var Item ={CallerID:data.data.hits[i]._source.caller_number}` .

Also, since `data.data.hits` is an array, it is more appropriate to use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) or a normal `for` loop instead of `for...in`.

Here is an example:

```
for (const hit of data.data.hits) {
    const item = { CallerID: hit._source.caller_number };
    console.log(item);
}
```

Event though the example above will work, it will not produce the required output the you've mentioned, to do that, you can use something like this:

```
for (const hit of data.data.hits) {
    const item = { caller_number_raw : hit.caller_number_raw, company_id: hit.company_id }
    console.log(item);
}
```

If you want to store all the newly created objects into an array, you can do something like this:

```
const output = [];
for (const hit of data.data.hits) {
    output.push({ caller_number_raw : hit.caller_number_raw, company_id: hit.company_id });
}
console.log(output);
```

This is even easier using a functional approach:

```
const output = data.data.hits.map(({ caller_number_raw, company_id }) => ({ caller_number_raw, company_id }));
```

Answer (score 0):

here you don't need the second for in loop because `_source` is an object.

```
for (let i in data.data.hits) {
    if(data.data.hits[i]._source.caller_number){
      var Item = {
        CallerID: data.data.hits[i]._source.caller_number
      }
       console.log(Item)
    }
   
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/e1cdpy3s/) of the solution.